# Find Chrome is running igntion or crankshaft

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, v8, chromium-embedded, embedded-v8

Is there any way to find chrome is running `ignition` or `crankshaft` V8 Engine?

As per https://v8project.blogspot.in/2017/05/launching-ignition-and-turbofan.html, chrome uses `V8 ignition` engine by default from version 59. I am looking for a way to enable ignition in chrome version#57 (in CEF environment).

When i use `--js-flags="--ignition --turbo"` in chrome 57, i am not finding much difference in js execution speed through chrome's performance inspect tools. So, i am looking for a way to query running v8 engine so that i will be sure enough to carry out my test on `crankshaft` or `ignition`; also, please do share any guidelines for performing JS load and execution performance.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Ignition in Chrome M57 is not officially supported. You can play with it if you like; it may or may not work; you're on your own.

Ignition does not replace Crankshaft. It replaces "full codegen", the old non-optimizing compiler. Ignition is not faster than full-codegen, but it saves memory (and has other, mostly internal/architectural, benefits).

There is no way to find out from JavaScript which compiler is being used. From the command line, you can use `--js-flags="--trace-opt"` to trace which functions are getting optimized by which compiler.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I am working on improving the startup time for CEF based app. This is one of the thing i have tried; using the switch for igntion and trubo is not making much difference in Chrome#57. I am wondering what makes the difference in Chrome#59 to give 30% improvements on startup time. Do you have any insight on this?

Comment: Between Chrome 57 and 59, the team has been hard at work improving Ignition and Turbofan ;-)